# Is there any method to use pagination on Applogic Web Chat plugin?

Tags: applozic

I use Applogic Pre-built customizable web chat UI and get contact json from my server api and pass json object in Applogic function.
Actually we have a lot of contacts, it is not possible to pass the all contact object in Applogic API at once.